# Delete record where it is null and joined to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I delete a record where a column is null, but the record I want to delete is part of another table.

For example I want to delete a course which has no students. The course table is linked to the students by course_id

```
DELETE COURSE_ID
FROM COURSE
INNER JOIN STUDENT
ON COURSE.COURSE_ID = STUDENT.COURSE_ID
WHERE STUDENT_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your data model is strange.  Students can only participate in one course?  I would expect a junction/association table, say `studentCourses` with one row per student and one row per course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question, as stated, you would use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM COURSE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STUDENT
              WHERE COURSE.COURSE_ID = STUDENT.COURSE_ID AND
                    STUDENT_ID IS NULL
             );
```

However, I suspect that you want to delete rows from `COURSE` where there is no `STUDENT` in that course.  For that, you would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM COURSE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM STUDENT
                  WHERE COURSE.COURSE_ID = STUDENT.COURSE_ID
                 );
```

Comment: What does SELECT 1 do?

Comment: @The_Bear . . . `EXISTS` simply checks for the existence of a row in the subquery -- the columns do not matter.  `1` is the easiest thing to type because something needs to follow the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you only need a subquery just for reference in the other table if present.

```
          DELETE
           FROM COURSE
          WHERE COURSE.COURSE_ID IN (SELECT 
           COURSE_ID FROM STUDENT where student_id IS 
          NULL)
```

Comment: This query, as far as Oracle is concerned, is invalid. You can't delete a column - you delete a *row*. But, you can UPDATE a column. So, which one of those did you have in mind?

Comment: thanks littlefoot i got your point it was indeed invalid just a misplaced typo i would say rather din had anything more than that